# Mute background music from dynamic theme

Tags: ps4, psn

I downloaded a dynamic theme off of the *PlayStation Network*. The look and feel of the dynamic theme is nice and smooth, however the music that plays can be somewhat tedious.

Is there a way to keep the theme while also muting the music that is playing in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in short, yes.

if you want to turn the theme music off, you can do so via  [Sound and Screen] > [System Music]. if you're wanting to replace the music from one theme with another, you might be out of luck.